# Routes configuration

Tags: centos, network-interface, route

I plugged a second interface in to a server with an existing functional interface(`em1`).  The second interface is configured for a different network, so I created `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-em2` (where em2 is my second NIC) with the following:

```
[acoder@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-em2
111.222.52.0/24 via 111.222.52.2 dev em2
```

The second configured gateway appears in `ip route`:

```
[acoder@server ~]# ip route
111.222.138.0/24 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src 111.222.138.214 
111.222.52.0/24 via 111.222.52.2 dev em2 
111.222.52.0/23 dev em2  proto kernel  scope link  src 111.222.52.69 
169.254.0.0/16 dev em1  scope link  metric 1002 
169.254.0.0/16 dev em2  scope link  metric 1003 
default via 111.222.138.2 dev em1
```

`em2` network config:

```
DEVICE="em2"
NAME="egna"
IPADDR=111.222.52.69
NETMASK=255.255.254.0
DNS1=111.222.1.1
DNS2=111.222.1.2
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
```

Unfortunately, I cannot ping or otherwise access 111.222.52.69.

What do I need to do so that the second interface (em2) works separately from the first (em1)?

Comment: netmask 23 or 24: use whichever one matches the network segment to which `em2` is attached.  Is it getting configuration from dhcp or `ifcfg-em2` ?  Is the machine 111.222.52.69 configured as 111.222.52.69/23 or 111.222.52.69/24 ?  Do things work with *no* `route-em2` (which looks like you're creating a static route to a locally attached segment--a route which should be automatically created anyway) (?)

Comment: I've added the `ifcfg-em2` config to the question.

Comment: This is my first experience using routes - I may be going about this the wrong way.   IP's on interface `em1` have a different gateway from those on `em2`.  I assume I need routes in this case, no?

Comment: Your `ifcfg-em2` shows a netmask of `/23` (`255.255.254.0`).  I cannot say whether `23` or `24` is *correct* for your network, but it should be consistent; not using `/23` in your ifcfg-em2 and `/24` in route-em2.  In general, you do not need an explicit route for the local network on each interface; as you can see, one is automatically created when the interface comes up.

Comment: `255.255.254.0` is the netmask I was given for the IP on `em2`.   I have more learning to do, I don't quite have a handle on your last sentence.

Comment: If I configure both network interfaces (`ifcfg-em1` and `ifcfg-em2`) with their respective gateways (and remove `route-em2`), the network fails to restart normally and I no longer have ssh connectivity.      If I shouldn't use routes, could someone please tip me off on what I should use instead?

Comment: You need routes, but you don't necessarily need any more *explicitly configured* routes.  In the last `ip route` output block in your question, there are three routes of interest: (1) any address in the range `111.222.138.1-111.222.138.254` can be reached on interface `em1`, because `em1` is physically attached to that network segment, with no further routing needed; (2) any address in the range `111.222.52.1-111.222.53.254` can be reached on interface `em2`, similarly; (5) any other IP traffic (`default`) should be sent to the router `111.222.138.2` on the network segment reached on `em1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44385/discussion-between-user4556274-and-a-coder).

Comment: The last ip route output from the question is when I have a route-em2 file containing the following: 170.140.52.0/23 via 170.140.52.2 dev em2. There is no GATEWAY configured in ifcfg-em2. Since these interfaces are on separate physical networks, shouldn't em2 have a separate gateway configured? If yes, why isn't that showing up in ip route output?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a route-em2 file for your second interface unless there is a third subnet (i.e. not the subnet configured on em1 or em2) that you want to route to via em2 rather than the existing default gateway accessible via em1.

By configuring 111.222.52.0/23 on em2 like you have done the machine knows to use em2 for all IPs in that subnet. There doesn't need to be another "gateway" for that subnet. The following route proves this:

```
111.222.52.0/23 dev em2  proto kernel  scope link  src 111.222.52.69
```

If after removing the route-em2 file and restarting your network service you cannot ping any 111.222.52.x IPs from the server it points to another issue.

Comment: Removed the routes-em2 file and restarted.   The ifcfg-em2 file does not have a gateway specified (is that correct?).  I can ping the em2 gateway using that interface, but am unable to ping anything else (again using the em2 interface).

Comment: I should add that em1 sits on a LAN and em2 is on a WAN.   Since the default gateway is on em1, is WAN (em2) traffic being blocked since it's attempting to pass through a private network (em1 gateway)?

Comment: OK that makes things clearer. I'm assuming when you say "unable to ping anything else" you mean addresses outside the 11.222.52.0/23 subnet. You want to remove the gateway from the em1 configuration and configure 52.0/23's gateway in the em2 configuration. If the LAN has any additional subnets that you need access to apart from 111.222.138.0/24 you can add a static route for them via a route-em1 file.

Comment: Using your suggestion above could I potentially add a route for subnet 111.222.x.x to pass through gateway 111.222.138.2?   If I don't hear back by later today I"ll give this a go.  Band practice calls..

Comment: 111.222.0.0/16 includes both em1 and em2's network so you need to add routes that are more specific for the LAN subnets.

Comment: I took a slightly different "route" and [got the configuration working yesterday](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307292/20107).

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with some help from [this page](http://commandline.ninja/2013/01/14/centos-policy-routing-why-yes-it-can-be-done/). Shout out to  @user4556274 and @root for their earlier help, even though I wound up taking a little different path.

Here is a network overview:

Existing and works:

```
em1: private LAN
     IP:      1.1.1.55
     GATEWAY: 1.1.1.1
     NIC #1
```

Need to add:

```
em2: public facing WAN
     IP:      2.2.2.88
     GATEWAY: 2.2.2.2
     NIC #2
```

Existing (working) `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1` network script:

```
DEVICE=em1
NAME=siteone
HWADDR=$MACADDRESS
IPADDR=1.1.1.55
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=1.1.1.1
DNS1=3.3.3.1
DNS2=3.3.3.2
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
```

That's what is on the server working now.

I now want to add another network script that is sequestered to the second interface, em2.

---

I begin by creating network script `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em2`:

```
DEVICE=em2
NAME=sitetwo
HWADDR=$MACADDRESS
IPADDR=2.2.2.88
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=2.2.2.2
DNS1=3.3.3.1
DNS2=3.3.3.2
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
```

Next, I edited  `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and added a new line at the bottom (below `#1      inr.ruhep`).  The new line contains `200    CHZBURGR`.  Make sure you have a tab and not spaces between `200` and `CHZBURGR`.  Btw, the name doesn't have to be `CHZBURGR` - refer to this route as anything that isn't already in use.

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
200     CHZBURGR
```

Next, create a new file called `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-em2` and add the following:

```
default table CHZBURGR via 2.2.2.2
```

*Note that 2.2.2.2 is the gateway of the second NIC (the public WAN).*

Finally, create a rules file called `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-em2` with the following:

```
from 2.2.2.88 table CHZBURGR
```

Now you are ready to restart the network* and test.

```
service network restart
```

* *I would strongly recommend either being at the physical server's console, or have iDRAC access.  If there are any mistakes you might unintentionally be locked out of your system.*